# Writing hostname and Serial number of multiple computers to local file using Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I am trying to write down the hostname and serial number of multiple computers separated by a "," on the master node(where i run the script from)
But i get this error when i run the script:

```
TASK [Write output to local file] **************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [Test -> localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to create temporary directory. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. Failed command was: PowerShell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -EncodedCommand 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, exited with result 127", "unreachable": true}
```

The master node is a linux server and the hosts i am gathering info from are windows hosts

Here is my script

```
---
- name: Gather hostname and serial number
  hosts: Test
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Get hostname
      win_command: hostname
      register: hostname_output

    - name: Get serial number
      win_command: powershell.exe -Command "Get-WmiObject win32_bios | select Serialnumber"
      register: serial_number_output

    - name: Write output to local file
      local_action:
        module: copy
        content: "{{ hostname_output.stdout }},{{ serial_number_output.stdout }}"
        dest: /opt/ansible/hosts.txt
```

nothing outputs to hosts.txt.

I have tried writing to ansible.log but nothing gets written their either

The hostname and seriel number writes out in the terminal, but the only problem is that it wont write to my local file

Answer (score 0):

Based on your debug message, the problem is clear: Your /bin/sh trying to connect to localhost with the PowerShell plugin. AFAIK you can't just run them in the same play, but you need to separate them. This might be a way to do this:

```
---
- name: your windows tasks
  hosts: yourwindowshost
  tasks:
  - name: task1 name
    ...

- name: your linux tasks
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: task2 name
    ...
```

If you want to move your variables between the two plays, use `set_fact` This topic might help you on this: https://serverfault.com/questions/962040/sharing-ansible-variable-between-plays

Comment: i have all permissions on the file that i am writing to, and with -vvvv i get the same + this in blue:

<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: oscadm
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'PowerShell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -EncodedCommand UwBlAHQALQBTAHQAcgBpAGMAdABNAG8AZABlACAALQBWAGUAcgBzAGkAbwBuACAATABhAHQAZQBzAHQACgAkAHQAbQBwAF8AcABhAHQAaAAgAD0AIABbAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAC4ARQBuAHYAaQByAG8AbgBtAGUAbgB0AF0AOgA6AEUAeABwAGEAbgBkAEUAbgB2AGkAcgBvAG4AbQBlAG4AdABWAGEAcgBpAGEAYgBsAGUAcwAoACcAJQBUAEUATQBQACUAJwApAAoAJAB0AG0AcAAgAD0AIABOAGUAdwAtAE